# Has the world in One Piece's world map been fully defined?

Tags: one-piece

From what I understand, Nami became a straw hat pirate to draw a map of the whole world. Doing so forces the implication that the whole world hasn't been traversed yet, in spite of the claims of Gol D. Roger the King of Pirates.

This leads me to believe that there is still a part of the world untraveled by any pirate. Because if there wasn't, then there wouldn't be a driving goal behind her character development.

So, can we really trust the current layout of the *One Piece* world? Or, has Oda made any announcements or claims that the world of *One Piece* as we know it is complete in its design?

Comment: Gol D. Roger sailed across the world to Raftel but he still had his path to follow when he entered the grand line, like Luffy and the other rookies each had their own path. I think there just isn't 1 complete map for the entire world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Piece world I think is more or less explored.

What Nami's dream is not to explore the unknown reaches of the world, but rather to map them.

She wants to draw a map of the world which includes all the 5 oceans, redline and maybe even the sky islands.

The reason why finding the one piece is important for her is because the One Piece is supposed to be in Raftel.

Though Gol D Roger and his crew have visited it, the location of the Raftel is unknown to the world and is not charted yet.

So Nami's dream is to draw a map of the world which has everything including the location of Raftel, Sky islands and all the other places for which proper maps do not exist.